# Dialog fragment with custom view

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to create a `dialogfragment` to show a list of things. Since the list must be loaded in async way, I'd like to insert in the dialog a `progressbar`. When the load process ends, I want to switch from `progressbar` to the `listview`. Currently with the posted code, when the dialog appears, it's empty, when I click on the neutral button (added in the code just to simulate the end of load process, nothing more), the `listview` appears without problem, so at the end I can't see my `progressbar` and I don't know why.

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setTitle(R.string.app_select);
builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
builder.setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.app_reset,
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                  //do something
            }
        });

//some code and create the adapter

builder.setAdapter(adapter, this);

dg = builder.create();
lv = dg.getListView();
//At beginning the list is invisible
lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
dg.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

        fl = (FrameLayout) dg.findViewById(android.R.id.custom);
        dg.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.progress, fl);

        /* debug code only to simulate the end of the process */
        Button b = ((AlertDialog) dialog)
                .getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //load end now the list must be visible
                lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        /* end debug code */
    }
});
return dg;
}
```

Edit: the layout progress.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="50" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: `the listview appears without problem, so at the end I can't see my progressbar and I don't know why.` i dont understant, isnt this what you want to not see the progress bar when the list if full? also show your xml

Comment: At beginning I have to see the progressBar, now the dialog is empty with only the three buttons, after the load I should switch to the list. The second part works.

Comment: I think the progress xml has a contradiction regarding the width: the FrameLayout's `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and the `android:layout_width="match_parent"` in the ProgressBar. Make the FrameLayout to match its parent, and see if this was the reason why your layout wasn't visible.

Comment: @ana01 I tried all the combinations, nothing to do

Comment: @greywolf82 In order to debug this, simplify your `progress.xml` layout (only let the `FrameLayout` with a strident color as background and a specific width and height, let's say 100 dp each) and see if the layout is shown. If not, it might be an attaching bug (not being attached at all, or not being attached where expected), although this doesn't seem to happen.

Comment: I changed strategy, I don't call setAdapter() but only setView() on the dialog with my own layout: a listview and progressbar. Then I call setAdapter() on my own listview.

Comment: probably your `fl = (FrameLayout) dg.findViewById(android.R.id.custom);` returns null. Right?